# Very Basic Ruby puts and gets

Tags: ruby, string, math

I have the following code. However I get a error. How is this supposed to be written.

```
puts 'What is your favourite number?'
number = gets.chomp
number = number.to_i + 1
puts "you would like " + number + 'much better'
```

Comment: -1. Not because it's n00b, but because you didn't include the error message.

Comment: Especially, since the error message already exactly answers the OP's problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It always helps if you include the error.  There are two ways to fix that error:

1. Interpolate the value: `puts "you would like #{number} much better"`
2. Turn it from a number to a string: `puts "you would like " + number.to_s + 'much better'`

The former, `#{...}` syntax, evaluates the content of the braces as Ruby, and then applies `to_s` to the result, before injecting it into the string. My two examples are literally equivalent.

As to why it fails?  `+` doesn't do type coercion in Ruby, which actually has very little implicit conversion going on, unlike other languages in similar spaces.